# Easyblog socialbutton not displaying properly

Tags: joomla-3.x

In my easyblog socialbutton, I'm getting a weird display issue, it shows two hyperlinks that say "St" and "Su", respectively.

[image]

Is there an easy fix to this? In firebug I can add css `display:none;`, but that's problematic since the css page originates from a stumbleupon url.

Comment: Have you tried clicking on them? Maybe that way you can realize what they do. It might be a broken link. You should remember that you can always try contacting the support team for your component.

Comment: They open a blank page in a new tab. If you hover over the link, you see javascript:void(0);

Comment: Could you provide link to your page if not resolved yet?

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that you are running the latest version of EasyBlog and associated modules.  There have been a number of issues posted regarding social media buttons on the StackIdeas forums in older versions of EasyBlog.  StackIdeas recently released version 3.9.2 of these modules and they do not get updated automatically when you update EasyBlog.